# How can I pass null from JQuery ajax and have it arrive in Django through REST call as None?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, rest

Here is my front-end Javascript/JQuery code:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "/myApi",
        data: {
           "myData": null
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function( data ) 
        {
            // Blah Blah Blah
        }
    }
);
```

My backend is a RESTful API which I have implemented using Python's Django framework. The view that accepts this call looks like this:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.info("request.POST['myData'] = |%s|" % request.POST['myData'])
```

This log line above yields is the following:

```
request.POST['myData'] = ||
```

But what I would like it to yield is:

```
request.POST['myData'] = |None|
```

When the jQuery passes the null value thru AJAX to the API, why does it get converted to the empty string? How can I receive it in my Python code as the None object?

Comment: try using `%r` instead of `%s` to interpolate `None`..

Comment: It's not a presentation issue at all. 
The underlying data is a empty string. So how I print it out is irrelevant.

Comment: "When the jQuery passes the null value thru AJAX to the API, why does it get converted to the empty string?"- it should not. Maybe something in between has filtered out or changed the value, normally it should be `'null'`. Under `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` contenttype, the body of request would be `myData=null` and Django uses `django.http.request.QueryDict` to parse it: `QueryDict('myData=null')` yields `<QueryDict: {u'myData': [u'null']}>` on my screen.